# Mandatory fields in php contact form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I need to make this form mandatory for the following fields.

Name:
Mobile Phone
Email Address:
Address Line 1:
Address Line 2:
City/Town:
County:
Postcode:
Service Requested Problem:
Item/PC Model Number:
Device Type:
Invoice Number:

I have tried using JavaScript by placing it in the header and in the index file but cant see to get either of them to work. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. I don't want to use PHP or have to re-code the current contact form.

PHP:

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists('func',$_REQUEST)) {
$func = $_REQUEST['func'];
} else {
$func = "";
}




function submitsq() {
require_once("header.php");

require_once("deps.php");

$rs_connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass) or die("Couldn't connect the db");
$rs_select_db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $rs_connect) or die("Couldn't select the db");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

require_once("common.php");
if (array_key_exists('sent',$_REQUEST)) {
$sent = pv($_REQUEST['sent']);
if($sent == 1) {
echo "<br><div class=noticebox><font class=text16b>".pcrtlang("Thank You for contacting us. We will contact you as soon as possible").".<br><br>";
echo pcrtlang("If you have any other Service Requests, you may submit them below").".";
echo "</font></div><br>";
} else {
echo "<br><div class=noticebox><font class=text16b>".pcrtlang("Service Request Not Sent").".<br><br>";
echo "</font></div><br>";
}
}

$sreq_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$rs_chkip = "SELECT * FROM servicerequests WHERE sreq_ip = '$sreq_ip' AND sreq_datetime > (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $withindays DAY))";
$rs_result = mysql_query($rs_chkip, $rs_connect);
$totalsubs = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);

if($totalsubs < $maxcount) {
echo "<br><div class=box><font class=text16b>".pcrtlang("Submit Service Requests")."</font><br><br>";

echo "<form action=index.php?func=submitsq2 method=post name=myform>";
echo "<table style=\"width:100%;\"><tr><td style=\"vertical-align:top;width:50%;\"\"><table>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Your Name").":</font></td><td><input name size=26 required type=text name=sreq_name  onFocus=\"this.form.submitbutton.disabled=false;this.form.submitbutton.value='".pcrtlang("Submit Service Request")."';\"></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Company").":</font></td><td><input size=26 type=text name=sreq_company></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=2><font class=text10i><br>".pcrtlang("Please enter at least one phone number").".</font></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Home Phone Number").":</font></td><td><input size=18 type=text name=sreq_phone></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Mobile Phone Number").":</font></td><td><input size=18 type=text name=sreq_cellphone></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Work Phone Number").":</font></td><td><input size=18 type=text name=sreq_workphone></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Email Address").":</font></td><td><input size=18 type=text name=sreq_email></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>$pcrt_address1:</font></td><td><input size=24 type=text name=sreq_addy1></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>$pcrt_address2:</font></td><td><input size=24 type=text name=sreq_addy2></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>$pcrt_city:</font></td><td><input size=18 type=text name=sreq_city></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>$pcrt_state:</font></td><td><input size=6 type=text name=sreq_state></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><font class=text14>$pcrt_zip:</font></td><td><input size=10 type=text name=sreq_zip></td></tr>";

echo "</table></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style=\"vertical-align:top\">";


echo "<font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Service Requested/Problem").":</font><br><textarea name=sreq_problem requires cols=40 rows=10 onFocus=\"this.form.submitbutton.disabled=false;this.form.submitbutton.value='".pcrtlang("Submit Service Request")."';\"></textarea>";
echo "<br><br><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Item / PC Model Number: ie. Dell, Apple, HP, etc")."</font><br><input size=36 type=text name=sreq_model>";
echo "<br><br><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Device Type: ie. Laptop, PC, Tablet, etc")."</font><br><input size=36 type=text name=sreq_type>";

echo "<br><br><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Invoice Number")."</font><br><input size=36 type=text name=sreq_pcid>";


if($allowusertochoosestore == "yes") {
echo "<br><br><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Preferred Store/Location").":</font><br><select name=storeid>";
echo "<option selected value=\"0\">".pcrtlang("No Preference")."</option>";
$rs_ql = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeenabled = '1'";
$rs_result1 = mysql_query($rs_ql, $rs_connect);
while($rs_result_q1 = mysql_fetch_object($rs_result1)) {
$storeid = "$rs_result_q1->storeid";
$storename = "$rs_result_q1->storename";
$storesname = "$rs_result_q1->storesname";
echo "<option value=\"$storeid\">$storename - &lt;$storesname&gt;</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
} else {
echo "<input type=hidden name=storeid value=0>";
}
echo "</select><br>";


if($recaptcha_enable == "yes") {
echo "<br><br><font class=text14>".pcrtlang("Please enter the words below").":</font><br>";
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
echo recaptcha_get_html($recaptcha_public_key);
echo "<font class=text10>".pcrtlang("This little test is just to make sure you are a real person and not a spammer so that our oncall technician only receives mobile phone notifications for genuine service requests").".</font>";

}


echo "<br><br><input class=button id=submitbutton type=submit value=\"".pcrtlang("Submit Service Request")."\" onclick=\"this.disabled=true;this.value='".pcrtlang("Sending Request")."...'; this.form.submit();\">";

echo "</td></tr></table></div></form>";
} else {
echo "<br><div class=noticebox><font class=text16b>".pcrtlang("Sorry, the maximum number of requests has been reached").".<br><br>";
echo "</font></div><br>";

}

require_once("footer.php");

}


function submitsq2() {
require("deps.php");

$rs_connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass) or die("Couldn't connect the db");
$rs_select_db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $rs_connect) or die("Couldn't select the db");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

require("common.php");

if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) {
date_default_timezone_set("$pcrt_timezone");
}
$currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sreq_name = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_name']);
$sreq_company = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_company']);
$sreq_phone = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_phone']);
$sreq_cellphone = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_cellphone']);
$sreq_workphone = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_workphone']);
$sreq_model = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_model']);
$sreq_type = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_type']);
$sreq_email = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_email']);
$sreq_addy1 = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_addy1']);
$sreq_addy2 = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_addy2']);
$sreq_city = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_city']);
$sreq_state = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_state']);
$sreq_zip = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_zip']);
$sreq_problem = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_problem']);
$sreq_storeid = pv($_REQUEST['storeid']);
$sreq_custsourceid = pv($_REQUEST['custsourceid']);
$sreq_pcid = pv($_REQUEST['sreq_pcid']);

$sreq_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sreq_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


if($recaptcha_enable == "yes") {
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($recaptcha_private_key,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die (pcrtlang("The words in the puzzle were not entered correctly. Please go back and try it again."));
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
}




$rs_chkip = "SELECT * FROM servicerequests WHERE sreq_ip = '$sreq_ip' AND sreq_datetime > (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $withindays DAY))";
$rs_result = mysql_query($rs_chkip, $rs_connect);
$totalsubs = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);

if($totalsubs >= $maxcount) {
header("Location: index.php?sent=0");
} else {

$rs_insert_sq = "INSERT INTO servicerequests (sreq_ip,sreq_agent,sreq_name,sreq_company,sreq_homephone,sreq_cellphone,sreq_workphone,sreq_addy1,sreq_addy2,sreq_city,sreq_state,sreq_zip,sreq_email,sreq_problem,sreq_model,sreq_datetime,storeid,sreq_custsourceid,sreq_pcid) VALUES ('$sreq_ip','$sreq_agent','$sreq_name','$sreq_company','$sreq_phone','$sreq_cellphone','$sreq_workphone','$sreq_addy1','$sreq_addy2','$sreq_city','$sreq_state','$sreq_zip','$sreq_email','$sreq_problem','$sreq_model $sreq_type','$currentdatetime','$sreq_storeid','$sreq_custsourceid','$sreq_pcid')";
@mysql_query($rs_insert_sq, $rs_connect);


if ($sreq_storeid != "0") {
$rs_qstores = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeid = '$sreq_storeid'";
$rs_result1 = mysql_query($rs_qstores, $rs_connect);
$rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result1);
$oncalluser = $rrow['oncalluser'];
} else {
$rs_qstoresid = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storedefault = '1'";
$rs_result1id = mysql_query($rs_qstoresid, $rs_connect);
$rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result1id);
$oncallstoreid = $rrow['storeid'];
$rs_qstores = "SELECT * FROM stores WHERE storeid = '$oncallstoreid'";
$rs_result1 = mysql_query($rs_qstores, $rs_connect);
$rrow = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result1);
$oncalluser = $rrow['oncalluser'];
}


$rs_quser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$oncalluser'";
$rs_resultuser1 = mysql_query($rs_quser, $rs_connect);
$urow = mysql_fetch_array($rs_resultuser1);
$useremail = $urow['useremail'];
$usermobile = $urow['usermobile'];


if(($useremail != "") && ($oncallsendemail == "yes")) {
require_once("sendenotify.php");
$from = "$useremail";
$to = "$useremail";
$subject = pcrtlang("Service Request Submitted");
$plaintext ="$sreq_name\n$sreq_company\n$sreq_addy1\n$sreq_addy2\n$sreq_city, $sreq_state $sreq_zip\n\n".pcrtlang("Home Phone").":\t$sreq_phone\n".pcrtlang("Cell Phone").":\t$sreq_cellphone\n".pcrtlang("Work Phone").":\t$sreq_workphone";
$plaintext .= "\n\n".pcrtlang("Email").": $sreq_email\n\n".pcrtlang("Device").": $sreq_model $sreq_type\n\n".pcrtlang("Problem").":\n$sreq_problem\n";
$sreq_problem2 = nl2br($_REQUEST['sreq_problem']);
$htmltext ="<b>$sreq_name</b><br>$sreq_name<br>$sreq_addy1<br>$sreq_addy2<br>$sreq_city, $sreq_state $sreq_zip<br><br><b>".pcrtlang("Home Phone").":</b>$sreq_phone<br><b>".pcrtlang("Cell Phone").":</b>$sreq_cellphone<br><b>".pcrtlang("Work Phone").":</b>$sreq_workphone";
$htmltext .= "<br><br><b>".pcrtlang("Email")."</b>:$sreq_email<br><br><b>".pcrtlang("Device").":</b> $sreq_model $sreq_type<br><br><b>".pcrtlang("Problem").":</b><br>$sreq_problem2<br><br>";
sendenotify("$from","$to","$subject","$plaintext","$htmltext");
}


if(($usermobile != "") && ($oncallsendsms == "yes")) {
require_once("smsnotify.php");
$smsname  = urlencode("$sreq_name");
$sms_cellphone  = urlencode("$sreq_cellphone");
smssend("$usermobile",pcrtlang("A Service Request has been submitted by")." $smsname - $sms_cellphone.");
}

header("Location: index.php?sent=1");

}
}

switch($func) {

    default:
    submitsq();
    break;

    case "submitsq2":
    submitsq2();
    break;

}

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" 
type="text/javascript">

<!-- hide script from older browsers
function validateForm(myform)
{

if(""==document.forms.myform.sreq_name.value)
{
alert("Please enter your full name.");
return false;
}

if(""==document.forms.myform.sreq_cellphone.value)
{
alert("Please enter your email address.");
return false;
}

if(""==document.forms.contact.sreq_phone.value)
{
alert("Please enter your phone number.");
return false;
}

}
stop hiding script -->
</script>
```

Comment: That `<!-- hide script` is not needed anymore. Furthermore, it's a syntax error in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrections to your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(myform) {
  var ele = myform.elements
  if("" == ele['sreq_name'].value) {
    alert("Please enter your full name.");
    return false;
  }

  if("" == ele['sreq_cellphone'].value ) {
    alert("Please enter your email address.");
    return false;
  }

  if("" == ele['contact.sreq_phone'].value) {
    alert("Please enter your phone number.");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

If the are any errors in your function then the form is automatically submitted without validation.

You also need to do validation on the server-side.